# Mouse wheel pressing button when scrolling

Tags: mouse, wireless-mouse, mouse-wheel, scroll-wheel, mouse-buttons

I have a `Promate Clix-7` mouse. I am having an issue where if I scroll down & up the wheel button "activates". I think it's because the wheel being too down, and it touching the sensor, but I'm not sure. How can I fix it? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Fixing a mouse may cost more than a new mouse.

Comment: It's a $12 mouse. Buy a new one.

Comment: If you want to try and fix it, disassemble the mouse (screws will be under the bottom pads) to determine if it's a fixable issue.  My guess is it's probably not from my own experience with taking apart a Logitech MX Anywhere 2S due to a middle click issue, but it was still fascinating to see how a mouse functions internally.